# Why can are the handles of node only sometimes locked in a straight line?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I don't understand the logic of Inkscape nodes. What I have figured out so far:

- If I Ctrl-click a cusp node, then it turns it into a Bézier node with two handles
- If I pull a handle back into the node, then that side of the node becomes straight (i.e., cusp-ish)

What I can’t figure out is:

- Why are the two handles sometimes locked in a straight line, and other times you can move them independently?

Comment: See also [this](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html).

Comment: If you can move them independently, the node is a cusp (or corner) node. Oherwise it is smooth or symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

Select a cusp with the node tool.

Click the cusp holding Ctrl => you get symmetric handles.

Click a node holding Ctrl. If the node had handles, they become symmetric.

Drag from the cusp holding Shift => you get an independent handle.

Click a handle holding Ctrl => the handle vanishes. There's no need to drag handles into the node.

Comment: what does "=>" mean?

Comment: @TylerDurden its a logical connective . It can be read "from that follows". Sorry for taking math symbols to my text.

Comment: Some of my nodes only have 1 handle and no matter what I do I can't get a 2nd handle back.

Comment: End node of an open path may well have only one handle with no problems. You can select an intermediate node of a path with the node tool and convert it to symmetric (=one click in the info panel). Hopefully you do not have active path effects , they resist many operations effectively. Expand the effects by applying Path > Object to Path or  remove them.